# Python - Package not found

Tags: python, api

I have one problem, I am a beginner with python and with APIs but this is something different, I think. I pip-installed one package with controlling spotify (play, show info etc.), just some basic stuff, but when I open cmd and type "spotify play" it should show what song is playing but instead is just like makes the app "blink" on my taskbar, like it restarted itself, hope you understand it. Only way to make the "spotify play" command work is to go to the folder with the script (cd command) and then it works, can I somehow make it work, without always needing to go into the Scripts folder?

(I am very new to this, please don't be mean, I am dumb, I know)

Here is the link to the package:

https://pypi.org/project/spotify-cli/

Comment: You need to add the `Scripts` folder where the app is to your environment's search path. The duplicate question I marked this with has detailed instructions for Windows 10.

Comment: I already did that but it doesn't work, don't know why...

Comment: Did you restart your `cmd` session?